# archive folder /usr/share/man

Tags: delete, gzip

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. There seem to be thousands of gzip archive files, eg stored under the `/usr/share/man` folder and its sub-folders, which I'd like to get rid of as they just clutter up my drive. There are many more also listed under `/usr/share/doc` folder and sub-folders and many other places besides these examples.

Is it safe to delete all of these gz files or would they ever be needed by the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I'll quote the steeldriver's comment:

> **It's a bad idea to manually delete any files installed by the package manager - it will get confused.**

I'm completely agree with it.

Then let's discuss the filesizes problem. I'm writing this from the Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 LTS with many applications installed.

Even on it I have the following:

> ```
> $ du -sh /usr/share/man
> 72M   /usr/share/man
> ```

But `/usr/share/doc` is bigger:

> ```
> $ du -sh /usr/share/doc
> 2,3G  /usr/share/doc
> ```

But why does `/usr/share/doc` is bigger? Let's run `ncdu` on this folder:

> ```
> $ sudo ncdu /usr/share/doc
>
> ncdu 1.11 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                                                         
> --- /usr/share/doc ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     1,5 GiB [##########] /texlive-doc                                                                                                                
>   153,3 MiB [#         ] /gnuradio-doc
>    67,3 MiB [          ] /fp-docs
>    25,3 MiB [          ] /kde
>    23,9 MiB [          ] /eagle
>    22,8 MiB [          ] /python-cherrypy3
>    20,0 MiB [          ] /libopenscap-dev
>    15,7 MiB [          ] /octave-htmldoc
>    13,6 MiB [          ] /nautilus-actions
>    13,4 MiB [          ] /gcc-4.8-base
>    13,0 MiB [          ] /uhd-host
>    10,8 MiB [          ] /HTML
>     9,4 MiB [          ] /maxima-doc
>     9,3 MiB [          ] /avr-libc
>     8,1 MiB [          ] /libx11-dev
>     7,2 MiB [          ] /libjanino-java
>     7,1 MiB [          ] /virtualbox-5.1
>     6,7 MiB [          ] /openjdk-8-jre-headless
>     6,2 MiB [          ] /python-logilab-common
>     5,7 MiB [          ] /graphviz
>     5,3 MiB [          ] /mibrfcs
>     5,2 MiB [          ] /asymptote-doc
>     5,2 MiB [          ] /ngspice-doc
>     4,7 MiB [          ] /autoconf-archive
>     4,5 MiB [          ] /liblcms2-dev
>     4,2 MiB [          ] /octave-doc
>     3,9 MiB [          ] /groff-base
>     3,8 MiB [          ] /latex2html
>     3,3 MiB [          ] /libgnuinet-java
>     3,1 MiB [          ] /texstudio
>     2,9 MiB [          ] /libsane
>     2,9 MiB [          ] /dblatex
>     2,8 MiB [          ] /dia
>     2,6 MiB [          ] /android
>     2,6 MiB [          ] /gcc-4.6-base
>     2,4 MiB [          ] /mesa-common-dev
>  Total disk usage:   2,2 GiB  Apparent size:   2,0 GiB  Items: 98961
> ```

So here I have about 1.5 Gb of useful stuff from TeXLive with TeX templates and documentation.
If you do not have TeXLive installed, then this folder would be smaller.

---

You should also know that both folders are used by *Help browser for GNOME* named Yelp from `yelp` package. So you can read many official documents offline.

If you open it, then:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and write here `man:man` (or call Yelp from terminal with `yelp man:man`) then you will get man-page for `man` command -

  > [image: yelp man:man]
- navigate to *All Help* then you will get many html-based help pages -

  > [image: yelp all help]

So these folders are very useful for offline use.

---

But if you are really know what are you doing, then you can remove documentation-only packages (having `-doc` suffix) with command like:

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l | grep -- '-doc\b' | awk '{print $2}')
```

(on my system it plans to remove 1 444 MB, in which are 1 086 MB for TexLive-related and 358 MB for others)